# UNIX install quota in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, quota

I am new to UNIX and can't figure out how to use the 'quota' command to see my disk usages. So I install “quota” using the following command

sudo apt-get install quota

But when I type in the command quota -v or anything similar, it doesn’t show anything. According to most website online (http://acs.ucsd.edu/students/quota.shtml#check-remove) , it suppose to show me all the quota limitation when I type in quota -v. can you please tell me how can I make it work or if I am doing something wrong here. your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `quota <your username>`. You can read up on the syntax of the command with `man quota` - If it's only supposed to print limitations, there might me no limitations enforced. If you just want to see general disk usage for the system, try `df -h`

Answer (score 0):

The reason `quota -v` does not show anything is obvious: There are no limitations set on your system.  (How to add limitations is another question.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a bit more work to enable quotas - you have to enable it on the partition and setup a couple of files - [have a look here](http://www.idimmu.net/2010/08/26/Disk-Quotas-On-Ubuntu).